# Как реализуется z-буффер в roguelike-играх?

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Допустим что объекты в игре - класс `GameObject`, у каждого объекта есть поле `Depth` - глубина, исходя из которой, объекты накладываются друг на друга как слои с глубиной, объект с самой высокой глубиной будет отрисован.

`Пример: '.' - глубина 0, 'А' - глубина 1, '@' - глубина 2`

(1)

```
.....
..@..
.A...
.....
```

При переходе '@' на клетку 'А', отрисовывается '@'

(2)

```
.....
.....
.@...
.....
```

Как реализовать хранение и проверку на глубину? Чтобы после обратного перехода 2->1 клетка с 'А' отрисовывалась заново и хранилась в памяти
Была идея с `ArrayList<GameObject>[]`, но как мне кажется это очень кривое решение

Comment: По идее персонажа вообще не нужно учитывать в "стеке" предметов, лежащих на клетке. В клетке где находится персонаж - всегда показываете персонажа. Где его нет - показываете самый верхний предмет в стопке (если предполагается нахождение больше одного предмета в одной клетке).

Comment: @insolor Идея в том, что это не стек. А очередь по глубине. Как хранить такие объекты

Answer (score 1):

Поидее лучше реализовать несколько отдельных массивов: Карта, с данными идущими сплошным текстом. Объекты с координатами и также персонажи.

В итоге можно в нужном порядке  отрисовывать карту. Или снизу вверх с наложением. Или сверху вниз игнорируя уже отрисованные сектора.

А если в клетке есть несколько предметов одного типа, то просто создать подкласс GameObject, который сам является контейнером для других GameObject и хранит стек внутри себя, возвращая тот символ, который стоит отображать. 
Другими словами, если возникает наложение, игровая логика сразу пакует их в этот класс-контейнер.

Comment: А что вы имеете ввиду под "несколько отдельных массивов". В одной клетке может храниться бесконечно много объектов. Вопрос как их хранить в памяти

Comment: @herrgott я имел ввиду типы объектов. В данном случае: Карта, Объекты, Существа. Тот Z буфер можно считать приоритетом отрисовки. Рисуем персонажа, если его нет - объект, если его нет - ландшафт. А уже на уровне этих типов можно объединять объекты в стеки. Просто так будет легче работать с картой на уровне игровой логики. PS Сам бы взялся за игрульку, да персонажей плохо рисую =(

Comment: А зачем рисовать?) Dwarf Fortress, adom - ascii forever) Ну вашу мысль я понял, попробую

Comment: @Herrgott, в DF большинство играют с тайлсетами, в новом adom'e изначально тайловая графика.